# Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component when several instances of a component is used

Tags: react-native

I don't why but when I put several same components in a View tag, RN throws a Invariant Violation: Text strings... error.

when I just put one component in my View then it works well

```
import React from "react";`
import { View, StyleSheet, Text } from "react-native";

export default class Alphabet extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>a</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "black"
  }
});
```

Alphabets.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from "react-native";
import Alphabet from "../SubComponents/Alphabet";

export default class Alphabets extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Alphabet /> <Alphabet />

        // one <Alphabet/> works as expected

      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
});
```

**EDIT:** when I put components each in a new line then it works too.

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Alphabet /> 
        <Alphabet />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the space between the two components will remove the error
instead of:

`<Alphabet> </Alphabet>`

Do something like this

```
<Alphabet />
<Alphabet />
```

Comment: but I'm not opening and closing Alphabet, I'm just using a `<Alphabet />`. I added new detail to my question.

Comment: I thought that you are using the open tag and close tag, in this case, remove the space between the two of them try to do one on top of another.

Comment: yes that way (each in a new line) works but I wonder why putting them back to back doesn't work?

Comment: That's because the space is consider as a text and text should be wrapped in <Text></Text>